# Codeigniter database update manually

Tags: codeigniter

Module

```
function update($id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('table', 'status=1');
}
```

Controller

```
function test()
{
    $this->load->model('model');
    $this->mdl_banners->update('1');
}
```

I tried to update a column of my database manually. I tried the above method but it did not work. Please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$table='tableName'; // or get it as parameter in function 
$data=array('status'=>1);
$this->db->WHERE('$id',$id);
$this->db->update($table, $data);
```

Below is a realtime example I am using it in one of my project

```
public function updatePage($data,$menuId)
{
    $item=array(
        'slug'=>$data['slug'],
        'content'=>$data['content']
    );

    $this->db->WHERE('id',$menuId)->update('pages',$item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was a great help

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your model is mdl_banners, then the controller code has to look like this:

```
$this->load->model('mdl_banners_model');

$this->mdl_banners_model->update('1');
```

The load has to load the model name followed by an underscore, same for the function calls later.

Malik's correctly answer points out another problem as well, you need to pass an array to update():

```
$this->db->update('table', array('status'=>1));
```

Answer (score 0):

//controller

```
function test()
{
$this->load->model('mdl_banners');      
$this->mdl_banners->update('1','1');
}
```

//model

```
function update($id,$s)
{
$data=array('status'=>$s);
$this->db->WHERE('$id',$id);
$this->db->update(table, $data);
}
```

try this..